# Stream de vídeo mms ou rtsp:// no android

Tags: android

Estou procurando alguma lib para reprodução de vídeo stream no formato mms://..., já tentei com VideoView mais diz que não suporta esse formato(Windows media player), procurando apps(na google play) que tem essa funcionalidade o que funcionou foi o VLC e RTSP Player, trocando o mms por rtsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anos depois surgiu libs para isso:

https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java

Answer (score 1):

[FFMPegMediaPlayer](http://wseemann.github.io/FFmpegMediaPlayer/)

Tradução livre da página principal da biblioteca:

> FFMPegMediaPlayer, é uma reimplementação da classe MediaPlayer do Android. A biblioteca lhe dá a oportunidade de usar uma interface unificada para tocar arquivos de áudios e streams.
>   Para mais informações sobre a biblioteca e exemplos de uso, visite o [javaDocs](http://wseemann.github.io/FFmpegMediaPlayer/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Não suporta o codec.

Comment: @Josinaldo, este foi a única lib que eu achei! ;(